# PHP socket shoud return json but returns warning

Tags: php, json, sockets

Never used socket before. I have to make socket to get an answer from server in json format. This is code:

```
$host = '11.11.11.1';//for example
$port = 1111;
$message = "xgm";
set_time_limit(2);
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Socket created \n";
if(!socket_connect($sock , $host , $port))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Connection established \n";
if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Message send successfully \n";
if(socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}


var_dump($buf);
socket_close($sock);
```

And this is response I get:

> - Socket created
> - Connection established
> - Message send successfully
> - Warning: socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [10045]: The    attempted operation is not supported for the type of object
>     referenced. in C:\wamp64\www\json\index.php on line 73
> - Could not receive data: [10045] The attempted operation is not    supported for the type of object referenced.

So it seems socket_recv  returns false. why? Is that because of json object in response from server? And how to fix that? Any directions?

Comment: Is this all of the code?  What is value of $buf  which is passed as second argument of socket_recv function?

Comment: I believe you will need to bind the socket to a local port to receive UDP packets. Use `socket_bind($sock, $address, $port)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP unlike TCP is a connectionless protocol, which means that two ends can exchange messages without having to establich a communication channel.
So, it's best to use `socket_recvfrom` and `socket_sendto`  because they work well with not connection-oriented sockets.

```
$host = '11.11.11.1';//for example
$port = 1111;
$message = "xgm";
set_time_limit(2);
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP))){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Socket created \n";

if(!socket_sendto($sock, $message, strlen($message), 0, $host, $port)){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Message send successfully \n";

if(socket_recvfrom($sock , $buf , 2045 , 0, $host, $port) === FALSE){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
var_dump($buf);
socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: Sorry for slow response. Your answer make sense.